# Load a subset of columns from file into python datatable

Tags: py-datatable

I have a huge csv file and I want to load only a small subset of the columns with `fread()`. In pandas `read_csv()`, I'd use the `usecols` argument for this and pass a list of desired columns.

How do I do this with a datatable? The [documentation](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dt/fread.html#columns) hints at the `columns` argument to `fread()`, but when I try this, it looks like that argument is for renaming the columns (similar as pandas `header=0, names=[]` arguments). The [fread examples](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/fread_examples.html) also give the same hint.

Comment: the examples in `fread` show how to do that, you can select with a `set` - so if you have columns a, b, and c, and you care for only a and b, you use : ``fread(data, columns={"a","b"})``, or with a list comprehension: ``fread(data, columns=lambda cols:[col.name in ("a","b") for col in cols])``. The fread examples that you refer provide these examples

Comment: Also note that you can prune the file with the`cmd` option, loading even lesser lines

Comment: Thanks! Now that you pointed my nose to it, I can see the example. I didn't expect a set to behave differently than a list, so I stopped looking after I had tried the list. And cmd is nice too! Allows me to put all grep and cut and head commands right inside by code for better documentation.